# java.util.ArrayList is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; model.servicecls is in unnamed module of loader 'app'

Tags: java, arrays, string, netbeans, jframe

I'm developing an object-oriented Netbeans application.

My J Internal Frame is giving a problem that says:

> class `java.util.ArrayList` cannot be cast to class `model.servicecls` (`java.util.ArrayList` is in module `java.base` of loader 'bootstrap'; `model.servicecls` is in unnamed module of loader 'app')"

I'm just trying to log and save information to a Jtable but doing so doesn't save or project anything to that Jtable.

In other Form it does work, so I have the assumption that it is because of the combo box but I can't solve it. I will leave my jframe code and its respective save class to which it is linked.

Comment: Well, I just noticed that I can't leave the code later